# Can I get Vue.js component as an instance?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I try to get the template of Vue.js component since I need it for another function.

First,
I have a function that needs a Vue.js component template because I want the data in the template to dynamically change and not just some static HTML.

Secondly,
I have a problem to get a template from Vue.js component. Maybe they are not allowed to do that but I am not sure. I am new to Vue.js.

But from my understanding of JS, maybe this can happen.

I am tried to do something like this:

```
let vmComponent = Vue.component('VueComponent', {
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'I am a Vue.js component manually.'
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Template Exchange</h2>
    <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  </div>`,
});

console.log(vmComponent.template);
```

I hope to get the HTML string when I run vmComponent.template

If this way of doing things is not possible. Is there any other ways I can get Vue.js component template as HTML String.

For example, maybe in a new.Vue({})

Comment: *I have a function* - what is this function? You likely have XY problem that should be solved in another way. Please, explain your case in the question and provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to access component template with `vmComponent.options.template`.

A template can be declared as a string for reuse:

```
export const template = `...`;

const vmComponent = Vue.component('VueComponent', {
  template,
  ...
});
```

This may not work with [pre-compiled templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#Pre-Compiling-Templates).